# 'Unsupported delete request.' removing photo tags via Facebook PHP SDK 4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have the following code and I'm trying to untag myself in a photo.

```
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('<appid>','<appsecret>');

$session = new FacebookSession('<my access token>');

$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'DELETE',
  '/<id of photo im tagged in>/tags',
  array (
    'id' => '<my fb id>',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
/* handle the result */

var_dump($response);
var_dump($graphObject);
```

I have both the permissions `user_photos` and `publish_actions` with the access-token that i'm using (as mentioned as required for removing photo tags).

However when I run the above I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message 'Unsupported delete request.'
```

I've tried to do exactly as in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/photo/tags) but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and why I'm getting this.

What can I do to get it working?

Comment: You are sure that it is a photo id? If you are I would file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: @WizKid yup done. The bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/658521840893467/

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of deleting a tag is by calling:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
  $session,
  'DELETE',
  '/<id of photo im tagged in>/tags',
  array (
    'tag_uid' => '<my fb id>',
  )
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

However, this is incorrectly documented. In addition, only whitelisted apps are able to delete tags via the API. The documentation also fails to include this. If you app isn't whitelisted, you will see the following error:

{   "error": {
    "message": "(#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3   } }

Comment: Let me try this. Is the whitelisting bit anywhere this is documented? The docs on the Graph API docs page specifically mention the permissions but not the whitelisting or the `tag_uid`. I don't want to make an app for it really. I'm just tagged in a whole load of spammy pics and I want a quick 5 minute way out. I regex who posts them and remove myself from being tagged in them.

Comment: No it's not documented. Thats what I'm trying to say. The error message `Application does not have the capability to make this API call` indicates that your app must be whitelisted to use the DELETE method for tags.

Comment: do you know how I can go about whitelisting it? Are there any other apis that need whitelisting in a similar way?